# Get associated HTTPSession of websocket session in spring

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-websocket

I have a simple web socket application that uses stomp. when a user visits a page it will automatically make a stomp connection to the server. The user is authenticated via spring security. When the user closes the browser i want the user to automatically logout. To do this I create a listener to listen for SessionDisconnectEvent. The problem is I don't have a handle to the httpSession associated with the websocket session? Is there a want to get the httpsession from the websocket session?

here's my code:

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/test">

        <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/sbapp">
            <websocket:handshake-interceptors>
                <bean class="com.sample.HttpSessionIdHandshakeInterceptor"></bean>
            </websocket:handshake-interceptors>
            <websocket:sockjs />
        </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
        <websocket:stomp-broker-relay prefix="/topic,/queue,/user" relay-host="localhost" relay-port="61613"/>
    </websocket:message-broker>
```

here's my websocket session listener:

```
@Component
public class StompDisconnectListener implements ApplicationListener<SessionDisconnectEvent>{

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(SessionDisconnectEvent event) {

        System.out.println("Stomp disconnect: " + event.getSessionId());
    }
}
```

I need a way such that when i get get a disconnect event I get the corresponding HttpSession then manually logout the HttpSession. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you find a decent solution to this problem? Running into the same use case here.

Comment: I am also interested in a solution to this problem. How did you end up solving it?

Answer (score 5):

Now Spring Session supports WebSockets. Follow [this guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/websocket.html) to add it to your project. Then, in your SessionDisconnectEvent listener, you can get your HttpSessionID this way:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessageHeaderAccessor;
import org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SessionDisconnectEvent;

public class WebSocketDisconnectHandler<S>
    implements ApplicationListener<SessionDisconnectEvent> {

    public void onApplicationEvent(SessionDisconnectEvent event) {
    String session = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.getSessionAttributes(event.getMessage().getHeaders()).get("HTTP.SESSION.ID").toString();
    }
}
```

(Other headers values you can access:)

`headers {simpMessageType=CONNECT, stompCommand=CONNECT, nativeHeaders={X-XSRF-TOKEN=[cb73273e-bff3-4eb7-965d-4c696e22c25a], accept-version=[1.1,1.0], heart-beat=[10000,10000]}, simpSessionAttributes={HTTP.SESSION.ID=6dd63204-d5ec-4362-8f37-29af5605298d, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN=org.springframework.security.web.csrf.DefaultCsrfToken@10b64145, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken=org.springframework.security.web.csrf.DefaultCsrfToken@10b64145}, simpHeartbeat=[J@3955ead4, simpSessionId=3x25c1e5}`

Be sure to register this as a bean in a WebSocket config file that extends ExpiringSession:

```
import your.package.WebSocketDisconnectHandler;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.session.ExpiringSession;

@Configuration
public class WebSocketHandlersConfig<S extends ExpiringSession> {

    @Bean
    public WebSocketDisconnectHandler<S> webSocketDisconnectHandler() {
        return new WebSocketDisconnectHandler<S>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you need a interceptor, you will get empty `sessionAttributes` without it.

You need to add `HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor` in the `dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
<websocket:message-broker
    application-destination-prefix="/test">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/sbapp">
        <websocket:handshake-interceptors>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor"/>
        </websocket:handshake-interceptors>
        <websocket:sockjs session-cookie-needed="true" />
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic, /message" />
</websocket:message-broker>
```

And then you will be able to get session in the controller:

```
@MessageMapping("/authorization.action")
public Message authorizationAction(
        SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor, Message message) {
    String sessionId = headerAccessor.getSessionId();
    Map<String, Object> sessionAttributes = headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes();
    System.out.println(sessionId);
    System.out.println(sessionAttributes);
    // Do something with session
    return new Message(...);
}
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below post.
https://spring.io/blog/2014/09/16/preview-spring-security-websocket-support-sessions